# Error on executing .msu file in vista platform

Tags: windows-vista

I'm trying to run the .msu file in the vista platform through command prompt my command looks like this:

```
" startfile.exe Windows6.0-KB942288-v2-x86.msu /quiet /norestart "
```

`startfile.exe` is a blank exe through which I'm executing the .msu file. The Error from the command prompt is

```
"the application has failed to start because its side by side configuration is incorrect.please see the application event log for more detail"
```

Same command it worked in the Spanish Os of the Vista platform.  When I tried in English OS of vista I got this problem. Is this dependent on any runtime library and I'm missing here I don't know?

Comment: What did the application event log say? (Run 'eventvwr.exe')

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to install the update, you should be able to use the built-in tool [WUSA.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934307) (it stands for Windows Update Stand-Alone installer) to install an MSU.  The syntax would be `wusa.exe Windows6.0-KB942288-v2-x86.msu /quiet /norestart`.

The problem you're having seems to be related to the program `startfile.exe`, but I don't see any need for it if you're just trying to install the MSU.